# Fatal error: Class 'Modelpaymentfreecheckout' not found OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, checkout

I am running Opencart v1.5.5.1 and all was going well, I am using PayPal for my standard payments which works but as an opening gift I am giving away some products for free. I have set the price to 0 and enabled the free checkout extension, but I am getting this error when I try to select "*Free checkout*" when I checkout.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Modelpaymentfreecheckout' not found in /home/content/00/10567100/html/reseller/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 49
```

I have uploaded a fresh copy of `catalog/model/payment/free_checkout.php` and `free_checkout.tpl` to their appropriate directories from a fresh version of OpenCart but it still does not work. I haven't been able to find anything online about this particular error either.

Any ideas would be welcomed :)

Comment: I never used it. But I suspect it's looking for some cached object. Maybe clearing the cache will eradicate the problem.

Comment: can you write to your post class name of free_checkout.php content? it can be about model class name of your new free_checkout.php file

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be that file you've described. If your system isn't able to load it then it's either permissions being incorrect on the file/folder or the content you are uploading is being corrupted. Have you downloaded the file there to see if it's in fact correct? I'd recommend using FTP to transfer either way using binary not ASCII if that's what it's currently set to as well